# copying a string from one pointer to another

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * find_dot();
char * find_end();

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

  char *file_extension[10];

  int i;
  for(i = 1; i < argc; i++){


    //if an option
    if(argv[i][0] == '-'){
      switch(argv[i][0]){

        default:;
      }


    //otherwise, should be the file
    }else{ 
      char *dot_location_ptr;
      char *end_location_ptr;
      char *filename_ptr = argv[i];

      dot_location_ptr = find_dot(filename_ptr);
      end_location_ptr = find_end(filename_ptr);

      memcpy(file_extension, dot_location_ptr, end_location_ptr - dot_location_ptr);
```

Where find_dot returns a pointer to the '.' in the argument, using strrchr, and find_end returns a pointer to the '\0' in the argument.

It compiles, but I get a segmentation fault. All I'm trying to do is capture the file extension as a string, and compare that extension to other strings.

Comment: You should have an array of `char`, not an array of `char*`: `char file_extension[10]`. Remember to copy the `\0` as well.

Comment: And there's one more thing I forgot to mention, see the edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> char *file_extension[10];
>      ^
> ```

You're not declaring `file_extension` right. You need a char array, not an array of pointers. Drop the `*`.

Comment: I've spent all day on this and thanks to you folks, it's finally working! Thank you!!